# How can we migrate outlook emails to Google domains

Tags: exchange, email-server, outlook, g-suite

### Our custom domain's [Microsoft Mail server](http://www.blogsynthesis.com/setup-microsoft-outlook-custom-domain/) To [Google App Mail server](http://domain.me/how-to-setup-a-custom-domain-on-google-apps/) migration:

We have the Microsoft Exchange custom domain mail server for our business which has been created as a free service previously and it was hosted in outlook.com (**mail server**). We have almost 20 accounts created in it. At last we would like to go with Google domain for Business [(mail server)](http://www.google.co.in/intx/en_in/enterprise/apps/business/).

In each account we have important email with attachments also, we have some documents in skydrive cloud server.

Now the challenging thing is we have to migrate all email and documents to the Google mail server. How it can be achieved?

Could you please help us to resolve this? any idea please?

Comment: What on earth is outlook mail server?! Do you mean Microsoft Exchange? if so what version?

Comment: Also have you got any onsite servers? How many users ? To answer your question people do need the full story!

Comment: He might mean Outlook.com hosted e-mail, too?

Comment: microsoft exchange server only. it was hosted in outlook domain.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Ask Google for a migration path since you would be paying to use their services.

Comment: I didn't think Outlook.com hosted custom domains ? :S Why don't you opt for a hosted exchange solution? I resell these options to clients and it's very affordable, even with SSO

Comment: Do you have control over your exchange server?

Comment: yes. We have the admin control

Comment: I think the most suitable protocol for migrating emails is IMAP. You should be looking for a tool, which can be scripted to download all folders for all users using IMAP and then upload them to a different IMAP server.

Answer (score 1):

I have positive experience with [MigrationWiz](https://www.bittitan.com/migrationwiz)

You can do

- Mailbox migration
- Public Folder migration
- Document migration

with it.

Comment: Thanks. is it expensive based on the size of the messages and count like that? or can be done freely

Comment: @Nava Yes it costs money but from my experience this is well-invested Money.
You can use the trial to evaluate MigrationWiz.
Here is the pricing table: https://www.bittitan.com/migrationwiz/pricing

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well the question, you want to migrate mails from client outlook application to google apps ?

There is a tool named "Google Apps Migration for Microsoft Outlook" this tools might work from both client and server side.

[Tools presentation](http://storage.googleapis.com/enterprisetraining/gapps/admin/GoogleAppsMigrationTools_Microsoft/en/MigrationTools_Microsoft.html)

[Administrator setup for Google Apps Migration](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176213?hl=en)

[Migration Tools](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/outlookmigration)

Answer (score 0):

## I am answering my question

We tried the migration tool which doesn't seem to workout. We got the message like *this tool is not available for your account*.May be it depends on the exact platform(we use windows 8) or i may not have any clue on this.

### How we have done is,

We did IMAP configuration in outlook client with two mail accounts (source + destination).Once the source mail got synced, we copied the **.pst** format files from the source account location to the same location of destination account location.That's it. It did the job peacefully.

Thanks for your answer and comment